# Saving two figures stored in two different objects to two different files without drawing on top of each other

Tags: python, matplotlib

From Seaborn I generate two separate AxesSubplots. I then get figures from those two subplots separately. I would expect that two objects would not magically interfere with each other without some kind of method being invoked that would make them do that. Why is this broken?

```
axsp0 = sns.distplot(cas_brs_min['dist'].dropna())
axsp1 = sns.distplot(pd.Series(np.log(cas_brs_min['dist'].dropna()), name='log(dist)'))

axsp0.get_figure().savefig('hist_dist.png')
axsp1.get_figure().savefig('hist_log_dist.png')
```

￼What I get is the following:

[image]

When I believe I should be getting:

[image]
[image]

I am also aware that there exists a object oriented interface for Matplotlib, although it doesn't seem anyone uses it in any tutorials. If I wanted to create a pairplot for this, how would I do that? All I see is `f, ax = plt.pairplot(2); ax[0].plot(...);` which doesn't seem to interface with anything I can do in Seaborn, which generates plots that I would seemingly have to assign?

Answer (score 1):

`plt.figure()` creates a new figure.

```
plt.figure()
axsp0 = sns.distplot(c...)
plt.figure()
axsp1 = sns.distplot(p...)
```

If you feel this doesn't give you enough control, you can create the axes to plot to and supply it to seaborn

```
fig0, ax0 = plt.subplots()
axsp0 = sns.distplot(c..., ax=ax0)
fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
axsp1 = sns.distplot(p..., ax=ax1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the second one. (I can't say I'm a fan of Matplotlib's magic interweaving plot syntax.) I presume that when I want to save it, I would use `fig0.savefig('blah.png')`?

Comment: Yes, or you use the code you used in the question, doesn't matter. What other command would you suggest to create a new figure that is less "interweaving"?

Comment: I'm not sure whether that is the right term to use, but I would have expected that when I create an AxesSubplot object, they are independent of anything else and getting a figure returns a new figure rather than spookily interfering with each other from a distance.

Comment: Seaborn's distplot only creates a new figure and axes if there isn't already one open. Hence in the code from the question, `axsp0 == axsp1`.

Comment: But I don't see any explicit connection between some unknown preexisting figure and the axes and I created. Looking into the type signature for `sns.distplot`, it says `ax=None`.

Comment: Internally there is some line `ax = ax or plt.gca()`. So if ax=None, the current pyplot axes is used.